# Why does my equation overflow in one environment but not another?

Tags: equations

I'm trying to transfer my equations to a new document which has its own (university-guidelines) sty file. But what I'm noticing is that this new document isn't able to automatically resize equations to make them fit within the margin.

This is what it looks like originally where it respects the margins

[image]

but this is what's happening in the new document, with a custom sty file:

[image]

One thing to point out is that the new document is set to double spaced, but I doubt that should make a difference in how it treats equations, and still, it should be able to resize equations so is there an extra command I need to add to the sty file or something to ensure that it does that?

Comment: Equations are *never* resized to fit. From what I can see, the bottom picture uses a larger type size.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it.  Is there a way to just change the text size and not the math?